# Application don't start anymore after using aop

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-aop

I use spring boot2, spring 5

For my controller, I have theses package

**com.murphys.lcm.controller.mvc**
**com.murphys.lcm.controller.rest**

I would like to  call getAllAdvice method for all my method in theses two packages

```
@Aspect
@Component
public class LogActionAspect {

    private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());

    @Before("execution(* com.murphys.lcm.controller.*(..))")
    public void getAllAdvice(JoinPoint joinPoint){
    }
}
```

Application don't start anymore I have many error

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'projectionDefinitionRegistrar' defined in
>   class path resource
>   [org/springframework/data/rest/webmvc/config/RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration.class]:
>   BeanPostProcessor before instantiation of bean failed; nested
>   exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
>   Error creating bean with name
>   'org.springframework.cache.annotation.ProxyCachingConfiguration':
>   BeanPostProcessor before instantiation of bean failed; nested
>   exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'metaDataSourceAdvisor': Cannot resolve
>   reference to bean 'methodSecurityMetadataSource' while setting
>   constructor argument; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name
>   'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration':
>   BeanPostProcessor before instantiation of bean failed; nested
>   exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
>   Error creating bean with name
>   'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration':
>   Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: warning no match for this type
>   name: com.murphys.lcm.controller [Xlint:invalidAbsoluteTypeName]  at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:496)
>
> Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
>   Error creating bean with name
>   'org.springframework.cache.annotation.ProxyCachingConfiguration':
>   BeanPostProcessor before instantiation of bean failed; nested
>   exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'metaDataSourceAdvisor': Cannot resolve
>   reference to bean 'methodSecurityMetadataSource' while setting
>   constructor argument; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name
>   'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration':
>   BeanPostProcessor before instantiation of bean failed; nested
>   exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
>   Error creating bean with name
>   'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration':
>   Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: warning no match for this type
>   name: com.murphys.lcm.controller [Xlint:invalidAbsoluteTypeName]  at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:496)
>
> Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'metaDataSourceAdvisor': Cannot resolve
>   reference to bean 'methodSecurityMetadataSource' while setting
>   constructor argument; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name
>   'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration':
>   BeanPostProcessor before instantiation of bean failed; nested
>   exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
>   Error creating bean with name
>   'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration':
>   Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: warning no match for this type
>   name: com.murphys.lcm.controller [Xlint:invalidAbsoluteTypeName]  at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:378)
>         Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
>   Error creating bean with name
>   'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration':
>   BeanPostProcessor before instantiation of bean failed; nested
>   exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
>   Error creating bean with name
>   'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration':
>   Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: warning no match for this type
>   name: com.murphys.lcm.controller [Xlint:invalidAbsoluteTypeName]  at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:496)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this

```
@Before("execution(* com.murphys.lcm.controller.*.*Controller*.*(..))")
```

that will get all controller (that suppose that your controller have Controller in their name)

just tested and that work

Comment: I would improve it by making it more general and easier to read at the same time, really finding all classes and methods in all subpackages, not just on one certain package level. The pointcut should be `execution(* com.murphys.lcm.controller..*(..))`. BTW, Robert, I think you should really read an AspectJ and/or Spring AOP tutorial instead of asking one question per syntax problem you have here.